# Display int of a tables MySQL

Tags: mysql, integer, int

```
<?php
    $result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM players WHERE nick = "'.$player.'"') or  die(mysql_error().":".mysql_errno());
    while($int = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo ''.$int['nick'].'';
    }
?>
```

How to get the number of a 'nick'?

Ex. I have ten nick of a random players in database.
And I want to show the number all of the players.

Comment: You need to make your post much clearer...

Comment: are you trying to count the number of total players, or get their unique number (like an ID)?

Comment: number of total players

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what you want, but your post isn't all that clear.

Assuming `$player` is unique, you will only ever return one row as you have added the condition. If you want to return a number from all rows in that table, you need to loose the condition and use `COUNT()`

EG:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS numberofplayers FROM players
```

PHP

```
$int = $mysql_fetch_array($result) 
echo $int['numberofplayers'];
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html

Just some advice - you should avoid the mysql api and use mysqli or PDO instead.